# Reading uncore counters through perf_event_open

Tags: c, perf

I'm writing a program to monitor uncore events using `perf_event_open`. I needed to monitor the `uncore_cha` type, but `perf` event open gives an invalid argument error.

According to the `perf_event_open` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html), dynamic PMUs can be set in the type field of the `perf_event_attr` structure.

The type value can be found in /sys/bus/event_source/devices/'pmu-type'/type. 
Upon setting this value, `perf_event_open` returns -1 and throws Error opening leader error. Upon examining the errno, it is found to be an Invalid argument error.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h> 
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <linux/pmu.h>
#include <linux/hw_breakpoint.h>

long
perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid,
                int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags)
{
    int ret;

    ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu,
                  group_fd, flags);
    return ret;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct perf_event_attr pe;
    long long count;
    int fd;

    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
    pe.type = 25; // // Type value 25 for PMU-Type uncore_cha_0
    pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe.config = 0x0111; //Event to be monitored
    pe.disabled = 1;
    pe.exclude_kernel = 1;
    pe.exclude_hv = 1;

    fd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

    printf("Measuring instruction count for this printf\n");

    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
    read(fd, &count, sizeof(long long));

    printf("Used %lld instructions\n", count);

    close(fd);
}
```

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please make your code a [mcve], e.g. by adding the `#include` statements. Just to make sure: did you make sure to execute your code as `root` if the `/sys/` path requires superuser rights?

Comment: I have updated the code to include all the header files so that it is verifiable. Also yes,  I was running it as the root user.

Comment: I added `perror("error");` after `if (fd == -1) {` and get `No such file or directory`, i.e. `ENOENT`. Quoting man page: "Returned if the type setting is not valid.  This error  is  also
              returned for some unsupported generic events."

Comment: What is your exact CPU model (full name of model), what is the linux kernel version (full version is printed by `uname -a` with your hostname, delete hostname and show it)? Does `perf list` lists the event in question? Does `perf stat -a -e uncore_cha_0/event=0x1111,umask=0x1/` work? (https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/700119). Uncore events are global and you can't count them for some single process, only for entire system (entire chip, NUMA node).